# SKLabelNode with Children not affected by gravity - not respecting zPosition

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I have a wrapper class to create a label node with some subnodes. This is the init for the class:

```
let label = SKLabelNode(text: word)
let background = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: size, cornerRadius: 0.5)
let mainNode = SKSpriteNode(color: color, size: background.frame.size)
label.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Center
label.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Center
label.addChild(background)
label.addChild(mainNode)
mainNode.zPosition = 1
background.zPosition = 2
label.zPosition = 5
self.node = label
```

In my main scene I instantiate the node, set its physics body and set the gravity for the scene:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake( 0, -10 );

let node = MyNode()
node.node.zPosition = 99
node.node.position.y = endOfScreenTop
  if let name = node.node.name as String!, let sprite = node.node.childNodeWithName(name) as? SKSpriteNode {
    node.node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
    node.node.physicsBody!.mass = 1.0;
    node.node.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0.0;
    node.node.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0.0;
    node.node.physicsBody!.friction = 0.0;
    node.node.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
    node.node.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    node.node.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
 }
 addChild(node.node)
```

I have 2 problems:

- The label appears behind the SKSpriteNode, even though the zPosition should place it at the front
- The SKShapeNode (that's just an insets to smooth the corners) doesn't appear at all
- None of the nodes are affected by gravity

PS. Even changing the following to true doesn't change anything:

```
 skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
```

PS2. the MyNode class has these properties

```
var node: SKLabelNode
var speed: CGFloat = 1.0
var word: String
var color: UIColor
var kind: Kind
```

Comment: and of course I forgot to copy the last line from the init, great....         self.node = label (I've added more infos at the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true` in the view controller (the default setting), some thoughts...

1. When `ignoresSiblingOrder` is set to `true`, Sprite Kit ignores sibling relationships when determining the order in which to draw nodes. It does not, however, affect the parent-sibling draw order.
2. In either mode, the parent is drawn first and then the child nodes are rendered. Normally, the children appear on top of the parent (if they're at the same location) regardless of the `zPosition`s of the parent and children! The exception is if a child's `zPosition` is less than zero. In this case, the child will appear beneath its parent (even if the parent's `zPosition` is less than the child).
3. It doesn't appear that you are setting `node.node.name` nor the `name` of the sprite node. If the names aren't set, the `if` condition will fail and the physics body won't be attached to `node.node`.
4. The default settings for shapes only draws a white border around its `path` (in this case, a rectangle). You should see this as an white outline around the sprite node. Setting `background.fillColor = SKColor.greenColor()` will show the `SKShapeNode` filled with green.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything works now. I deleted the SKSpriteNode and just kept the Shape not using background.fillColor. I really didn't think that the ignoresSiblingOrder acted like that during parent-sibling draw order.

Comment: `ignoresSiblingOrder` should be `true` in the first sentence and in bullet 1. I mistakenly set it to `false`. I've updated my answer. Sorry about that.